# How can a screen be projected on a transparent glass?

Tags: optics, telecommunication, glass

I am building something similar to Google Glasses although not exactly that. I am trying to find a way to project my 0.96inch OLED on a glass, but it can't block the front view.

What I tried to do is to set the OLED display at 45deg with the glass but what it does is a good reflection at far corner which is very hard to see, to see clearly, I need to see it from 90deg angle with the screen, like a mirror.

But I want the screen to be visible while looking at the glass directly from front.

I guess this may be possible in the following ways:

1. Total internal reflection, but no idea how the setup may look like
2. I think, something similar to projectors can work, but how to get the 0.96inch through a small hole and fall it on a glass?

Here is what I tried and problem I faced
[image: Projection details]

I am out of ideas and depending on your help :(

Comment: HI, we need some more info.  PLease post a diagram showing the configurations you are considering.   In addition, explain where the viewers are placed -- what does "can't block front view" mean here?   And do you really want an image on the glass, or just reflect the image so it's focussed by the viewer's eye?

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment, I am adding the details shortly, and yes, I want to reflect the image so it's visible on the glass, like smart glasses

Comment: Tilt the transparent glass at a 22.5 degree angle? (half of 45 degrees)

Comment: @user253751 Is there any other way without rotating the main transparent glass?

Comment: make a "Fresnel glass" consisting of tilted segments that line up straight, perhaps? That will distort the view straight through the glass. \\\\\\\\\\ <- this shape but vertical. Maybe someone else knows a way to do it without rotation, but as far as I'm aware, you have to rotate the glass to get the reflection in the right place.

Comment: you could also have a half-blocking glass, e.g. interleaved strips of white paint and strips of clear glass, and then on the painted section you could see the screen projection (assuming the screen was projected with appropriate optics) and through the clear section you could see through the glass. That wouldn't not block the view but it also wouldn't block the view completely. You could change the ratio of painted space and clear space

Comment: @user253751 or even better, a uniform random spray of reflective paint so the average transmission is 50%

Comment: but really, I feel like the "correct" way to do this is to tilt the glass 22.5 degrees.

Comment: thanks, i have tried that and it works, i am using this method, rotating 22.5 deg